# Django: Create webhook receiver

Tags: python, django, typeform

I am currently trying to implement webhooks for [this site](https://developer.typeform.com/webhooks/walkthroughs/). I can't find much in the documentation about creating a webhook. Do you have any good repositories or pages I can look into to get a better understanding of how to build a webhook for Typeform?

Comment: Receiving a webhook isn't any different from receiving any other kind of request. If the API needs you to do certain things in response, that should be covered in the docs for the API itself, not Django's.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As Daniel pointed out in their comment, a webhook receiver is just another endpoint in your Django app, accepting POST requests and dealing with JSON input.

I tried to put together an example, hope it helps.

```py
import json
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST

@csrf_exempt
@require_POST
def webhook_endpoint(request):
    jsondata = request.body
    data = json.loads(jsondata)
    for answer in data['form_response']['answers']: # go through all the answers
      type = answer['type']
      print(f'answer: {answer[type]}') # print value of answers

    return HttpResponse(status=200)
```