# Creating an API from typeform for Python

Tags: python, api, typeform

I am very new to coding, especially in API's. I am trying to creating a link between typeform and python, so when someone submits their form I can process their information. For example, when someone submits their form, I would like to assign question 1 to varible1, and question 2 to variable2, then do some calculations such as varible1/varible2 = varible3. Eventually, I want to send that data elsewhere, such as google sheets and Databox. But for now, I'm just trying to connect python and typeform.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post some code examples

Answer (score 3):

Typeform has web hooks -- that is what you are looking for.

https://developer.typeform.com/webhooks/

So on each form submit - the hook you configure will be called.

In your case you want the hook to be to your publicly accessible python script.

All values filled in typeform will be available as json -- and then you can perform the calculations you need in your server side python script -- and then on post to other systems/db.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

As Mayank pointed you are probably looking to use something called *Webhook*.

*Webhooks* are a way for applications to notify another application (in this case yours) when an event occurs, in this case, a response to a typeform has been submitted.

Imagine kids in the car asking constantly "are we there yet?", like you would do with an API to check if there is a new response to your form.

Webhooks are more like "please let me know when we arrive at destination".

Typeform will send your app a JSON object containing all the details of the response submitted.
Your Python would have to extract data from this JSON object and then decide its own logic.

Here is an example on a Django app explained on another [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53974149/django-create-webhook-receiver/53986799#53986799)

```
import json
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST

@csrf_exempt
@require_POST
def webhook_endpoint(request):
    jsondata = request.body
    data = json.loads(jsondata)
    for answer in data['form_response']['answers']: # go through all the answers
      type = answer['type']
      print(f'answer: {answer[type]}') # print value of answers

return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

To activate webhook on your form, you need click on *Connect > Webhooks* and create a webhook there.
Here is a more detailed guide on [Typeform Help Center](https://help.typeform.com/hc/en-us/articles/360029573471-Webhooks)